Multiple Newtonsoft options
I need the returns from only one controller of my solution to serialize the enums into string (use Newtonsoft StringEnumConverter), I tried all the solutions I could find, none of them works, knowing that I can't set this parameter on the enum classes or attributes because they're shared by other controllers.
It would be perfect if I could define 2 sets of options like that:
services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
    options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
    options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK";
}); // default one
services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
    options.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
    options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat;
    options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssK";
}); // special one

and specify which one to use in controllers.
My project is in .NET 5.0.

What asp.net[-core] version are you using?  Also, do you need the custom options for deserialization (model binding), serialization (formatting), or both?

The project is in .NET 5.0, I only need the enums are serialized in string in the responses of my controller actions.

As a quick fix I believe you can just do return Json(model, serializerSettings: customJsonSerializerSettings); in that specific controller.  According to the docs, When using Newtonsoft.Json, this should be an instance of JsonSerializerSettings.  Is that sufficient for your needs?

Or if you are inheriting from ControllerBase use return new JsonResult(model, customJsonSerializerSettings);

I think I'm gonna use JsonResult to resolve my problem but I lose information, because I used Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc Conflict/Created/NoContent/Ok... methods to manage the response http status.

If JsonResult doesn't 100% work for you, might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing an example controller method where information would be lost?  It could contain dummy code and objects as long as it demonstrates the problem.  Also, in your comment above Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc Conflict/Created/NoContent/Ok was truncated so I'm not sure to what you were referring.  Thanks!

To achieve your requirement you could configure Newtonsoft JSON globally in Startup.cs. Then, create a JsonCustomizationFilter action filter that sets custom JsonSerializerSettings with StringEnumConverter. Apply this filter to controllers/actions needing custom serialization. Modify controller's Json method to use these settings from HttpContext.Items
